# "The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for requests" In .Net React Application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio, npm, create-react-app

When I try to run my project I always get this error:

> ```
> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors
> occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the
> create-react-app server was listening for requests. The error output
> was:
>
> )) System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.GetResultCore(bool
> waitCompletionNotification)
>
> InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without
> indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for
> requests. The error output was:
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer.ReactDevelopmentServerMiddleware.StartCreateReactAppServerAsync(string
> sourcePath, string npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
>
> Stack Query Cookies Headers AggregateException: One or more errors
> occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited
> without indicating that the create-react-app server was listening for
> requests. The error output was: ))
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.GetResultCore(bool
> waitCompletionNotification)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout<T>(Task<T>
> task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, string message)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext
> context, HttpClient httpClient, Task<Uri> baseUriTask,
> CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, bool proxy404s)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass2_0+<<UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer>b__0>d.MoveNext() Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
> Garrigues.BDC.Web.Classes.LoggingMiddlewareFront.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext, IUserInfo userInfo) in LoggingMiddlewareFront.cs
> +
>                 await _next(httpContext); Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
>
> Show raw exception details InvalidOperationException: The NPM script
> 'start' exited without indicating that the create-react-app server was
> listening for requests. The error output was:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer.ReactDevelopmentServerMiddleware.StartCreateReactAppServerAsync(string
> sourcePath, string npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
> ```

I've tried everything I've seen online, and it still fails.
I've executed "npm install" and a lot of npm commands I've seen in similar questions online.
I've updated npm, node.js and visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Un-Install your Node and install it again.
Please also install nvm( node version manager ).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I've just done as you say, but the same error persists.

Comment: Hello, I think that your node version is not supporting your project package.json.

Comment: Hi, I'm using the 16.14.0 version (although I've tried with 16.0.0, 15.0.0 and 14.6.0 too) Which version do you suggest me to use? thank you

Comment: And what is your npm version?

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution as such but running `yarn start` (or `npm start`, depending on what you're using) should give you the actual error message.

Comment: this is usually when I'd comment and vote to close for lacking detail/clarity